# JFrame Error java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, calculator

I have been trying to create a `JFrame` Calculator but am getting the error `java.lang.nullpointer.exception`. It says that I have a problem in the line where I say:

```
GuiCalc go = new GuiCalc();
```

Here is all of the code:

```
package home.personalprojects.jordan;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GuiCalc extends JFrame
{

    private JButton calculate;
    private JTextField num1field, num2field;
    private JComboBox operationbox;
    private JLabel label1, label2, label3;
    private String[] operationposs = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};
    String operation;
    int num1, num2, answer;

    public GuiCalc(){

        super("Calculator");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        operationbox = new JComboBox(operationposs);

        calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        calculate.setToolTipText("Enter Two Numbers And Then Select An Operation To Find An Answer");

        label1 = new JLabel("Number 1: "); 
        num1field = new JTextField("", 10);
        label2 = new JLabel("Number 2: ");
        num2field = new JTextField("", 10);

        operationbox.addItemListener(
            new ItemListener(){
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                    if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){

                        int temp;
                        temp = operationbox.getSelectedIndex();
                        switch(temp){
                        case 0:
                            answer = num1 + num2;
                        case 1:
                            answer = num1 - num2;
                        case 2:
                            answer = num1 * num2;
                        case 3:
                            answer = num1 / num2;

                    }
                }
            }
        });


        calculate.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("The Answer: " + answer, event.getActionCommand()));
                }
            }
        );

        add(label1);
        add(num1field);
        add(label2);
        add(operationbox);
        add(label3);
        add(num2field);
        add(calculate);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        GuiCalc go = new GuiCalc();
        go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        go.setSize(500,500);
        go.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: Please paste the whole stack trace, along with what the line numbers correspond to.

Comment: It should say additional line number in method GuiCalc()

Answer (score 2):

When I run your code I get...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1086)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:998)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:562)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
    at testcalc.TestCalc.<init>(TestCalc.java:79)
    at testcalc.TestCalc.main(TestCalc.java:87)
```

Which points to

```
add(label3);
```

Which suggest that `label3` has not being initialised.

Comment: Even label3 is null, will it give an exception of nullpointer?

Comment: Yes, how could you possibly add a `null` value to a container?  It doesn't make sense (to me anyway)

Comment: I did that and now it is giving me the same error message except for the bottom line which is now gone

Answer (score 0):

As [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18326013/2698114) says, you haven't initialized `label3` by the time you've called `add`. The `JFrame` inherits from `java.awt.Component`, whose `add(Compontent comp)` method [throws an exception if passed a null argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29). Make sure to construct the `JLabel` before `add`ing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a value to label3 before you add it to this:

```
label3 = new JLabel("");
```

or

```
label3 = null;
if (label3 != null) this.add(label3);
```